# Cannot create a bibliography section for my PhD proposal

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing my PhD proposal. I have a problem with making a bibliography section for my document.

Instead of having one document, I have separate .tex files for all of my sections, and include them using \input{section-1} in my main.tex.

To create the bibliography section, I am using

```
\documentclass[12]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\input{sections/introduction}
\input{sections/exp_approach}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

However, it doesn't print out the bibliography section. And all the \cite{} in my sections cannot communicate with the references in my refs.bib file.

Could anyone please let me know what I've been doing wrong? and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as you've shown us, thinks look ok. But, two questions. Have you cited any references in your `\input`ed files? Have you run `latex` -> `biber` -> `latex` to compile?

Comment: First question: I did cite references in my inputed files. Second question: No, I did not. I am using sharelatex.com to compile my document. Would that be the problem? Should I download a latex compiling software? I am totally new to latex that I depend entirely on the help document posted on sharelatex.com.

Comment: Actually, sharelatex should be taking care of that, so that must be something else then. I'm not really acquainted with sharelatex. But then, other questions. Does your other parts of the document appear normally (I mean the inputed sections)? Do your citation call outs appear correctly? Do you get any error messages when sharelatex builds your document?

Comment: I think I found a solution. I tried to comment all of my \input statements out, and then compile the document. Now, I un-commented all the \input statements and re-compiled. It worked. Another problem that I found was there was a weird character in one of the references that I copied from google, which has been given me error.

Comment: If you found a solution by yourself, may this question be closed then? In it's current state, it is probably not very useful to others. Regarding your weird character, see if this discussion https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430379/105447 can help you.

Comment: Yes, please help me close this question. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.