# How to put a hyphen in bibliography

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I would like to cite [this](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/service-provider/visual-networking-index-vni/mobile-white-paper-c11-520862.html) white paper, but I get something as shown in the figure below

[image]

How can I remove the strange sign between 2016 to 2017. I want something like 2016-2017.

I haven't found any similar question that addresses this yet.

Edit:

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Note in references file I have:

```
@Report{cisco,
  title = {Cisco Visual Networking Index: Global Mobile Data Traffic Forecast Update, 2016–2021 White Paper},
  year  = {2017},
  date  = {2017-03-28},
  url   = {https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/service-provider/visual-networking-index-vni/mobile-white-paper-c11-520862.html},
```

Comment: You need to elaborate a minimum latex code that generates the pdf file and present that error to be able to help you, you may not have included adequate coding packages.

Comment: It looks like you have a typed endash between 2016 and 2021. Substitute that by `--` (two hyphens).

Comment: For my first test I find no errors if I use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` before this `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`; let me know if it solved the problem...

Comment: @gusbrs I tried using the `--`. It looks better, but I still have that `U` sign infront of the hypen.

Comment: @JLeonV. with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` it worked. At first it displayed this error: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'. 2016 � .

Comment: Try the following. In your file, delete the whole stretch `2016–2021`, and then retype it manually (no copy-paste) with the two hyphens.

Comment: Thanks all! Both answers from @J Leon V. and @gusbrs worked fine!

Comment: @JLeonV. If you'd like to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the package `cite`, then add certain packages to add color and hyperlinks, the `natbib` package is not compatible with that style of bibliography, this package allows to quote with author names automatically.

*I use arara to automate my compilations, has no effect on other compilers by its comment format ..

Result:

[image]

MWE:
Main latex file:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% arara: bibtex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding for interpreter
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Allows the definition of hex colors
\usepackage{colortbl} % colors library.
\definecolor{klein}{HTML}{002fa7} % Klein blue
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=True,citecolor=red,urlcolor=klein]{hyperref}% For Hyperlinks

\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
%\usepackage{natbib} %Is not compatible with IEEEtran %Try using plainnat
% Enables to cite using author names  commands \citet \citep
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-8]

    Some author \cite{cultLIBRE}, another author or reference\cite{cisco}.\\


    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

    \bibliography{references}

 \end{document}
```

Blibliography file: references.bib

```
@article{cultLIBRE,
  author = { Lessig, Lawrence },
  title = {{Free Culture: How Big Media uses Technology and the Law to lock down Culture
  and control Creativity}},
  journal ={ Versión en Español, por LOM Ediciones},
  year = {2005},
  numpages ={270},
  url = {https://www.derechosdigitales.org/culturalibre/cultura_libre.pdf},
  pages={31-209},
  Abstract={Todo sobre la cultura libre},
  language = {spanish}}

@Report{cisco,
    title = {{Cisco Visual Networking Index: Global Mobile Data Traffic Forecast Update, 2016–2021 White Paper}},
    year  = {2017},
    date  = {2017-03-28},
    url  = {https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/service-provider/visual-networking-index-vni/mobile-white-paper-c11-520862.html}}
```

Comment: You mean `natbib` package is not compatible with IEEE style of bibliography? Also, `cite` is included in the IEEE template. I am asking as I since I want my references do not conform with the IEEE style. Thank you